# GetObject Function in VB 6 is throwing the Error number 429 in Windows 7

Tags: excel, vb6

I am exporting the data from my application to excel. For this i am checking whether any excel windows are open and then creating the excel application object. Like as mentioned below.

```
lHwnd = FindWindow("XLMain", vbNullString)

 If lHwnd = 0 Then
      \\create new application
      Set GetExcelApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
  Else
      \\get existing application
      Set GetExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 End If
```

But if any excel windows are already open then this code is throwing the error 429.In Windows Xp this code is working fine for all scenarios but in Windows 7 its throwing the Error 429 while running the exe.
How can i solve this. Please advice..

Comment: If you have 64 bit Office you will not be able to automate from 32 bit VB6.

Comment: No its 32 bit office 2007

Answer (score 0):

Error 429 - ActiveX component can't create object means that the Excel.Application object is not registered on your Windows 7 machines. This could be because Excel is not installed, or improperly installed. I would go to the Control Panel=>Programs and Features, select Microsoft Excel xx.0 or Office xx.0 and select Change. Select the Repair option.

Comment: Hi mark.. Office 2007 is installed properly. I got some info but it didnt work. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238610

Comment: That's interesting - I never knew that. But it makes sense as an optimisation. BTW, I take it that this line gets executed:  Set GetExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Comment: Yes.I am getting the error while this gets executed. Set GetExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")